# ß becomes SS in bibliography with BibLaTeX/Biber and XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, biblatex, xetex, biber, input-encodings

**Background:**

I am using BibLaTeX, Biber and XeLaTeX to write a book that contains a bibliography. The bib-file is encoded as UTF-8 and contains "special" characters such as umlauts (ä, ö, ü) and sharp s (ß).

**Problem:**

When I compile the document, the "ß" are replaced by "SS" in the bibliography, as in the following:

[image: "ß" replaced by "SS"]

Note that the umlauts are ok.

Compiling the source with pdfLaTex yields the desired result, as in the figure below, but for certain reasons I would like to stay with XeLaTeX.

[image: desired result with pdfLaTeX]

Here are the **minimal working examples**:

.tex-file

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % output font encoding
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp} % beautiful fonts (latin modern).
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input language. Required only for pdfLaTeX.
\usepackage[ngerman, UKenglish]{babel} % language support
\usepackage{csquotes} % prettier quotes
\typearea[current]{calc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex} % biblatex
\addbibresource{test.bib} %biblatex

\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\author{henning}
\maketitle

Here is some reference \parencite{Bluehdorn2010}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

.bib-file

```
@INCOLLECTION{Bluehdorn2010,
  author = {Ingolfur Blühdorn},
  editor = {Sebastian Bukow and Wenke Seemann},
  title = {Win-win-Szenarien im Härtetest. Die Umweltpolitik der Großen Koalition
    2005-2009},
  booktitle = {Die große Koalition},
  year = {2010},
  publisher = {VS Verlag},
  pages = {211 -- 227},
  address = {Wiesbaden},
  keywords = {germany, grand coalition, environment},
  timestamp = {2012.07.18}
}
```

Note that the problem persists whether or not I use `\usepackage[utf]{inputenc}`.

**Question**:
How can I configure XeLaTeX to produce sharp s instead of double-s?

Any hints are very much appreciated!

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26338/4778

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `xelatex` use

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, DIV=calc]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % output font encoding
%\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp} % beautiful fonts (latin modern).
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input language. Required only for pdfLaTeX.
\usepackage{fontspec}
...
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Also the methods in the other answers do not work either. This happens for biblatex with biber. Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is: `{\ss}` instead of `ß` or `ss`.

Comment: Are the curly braces necessary? It works without them as well.

Comment: Well, if you have gro\sse, it will read that as \sse - which it' can't recognise - not \ss+e. The curly braces are a good way around that, though not the only one.

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, but if there's no letter after it...

Comment: `Gro\ss e` or `Gro{\ss}e`, both ways are working, yes :-)

Comment: @Au101 Also the space works and it's easier to type! :P

Comment: @Alenanno: `Gro\ss{}e` or `Gro\ss e` are preferrable; `Gro{\ss}e` may cause bad kerning or similar. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229166/28608).

Comment: @Alenanno - The short answer to your question is, "yes" -- *in a bib file*. For a longer answer, see the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

Comment: @Mico Oh good to know. :D